# Progress Bar phpSpreadSheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am creating an Excel with PhpSpreadsheet (no prob with that). I am working with MVC pattern so the flow is :

1. User press download button and call function in controller
2. function in controller call a function in an helpers to create the excel

Now it's a very very long task and I would like to show the progress of this long task (like a download bar). I have tried with all things that I know (ajax polling , iframe, sse, session variable, static variable) but none seem to work.

Could you help me ?

The problem is that if for example I use `echo` in the middle of the process, it will collide with the header of the excel created. I have tried also with `header_remove()` but it does not work.

Comment: Could you please post a code sample illustrating what you have tried so far and where specifically you are experiencing issues?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/indeshan/downloader_with_progressbar) may help. Thanks!

Comment: What are you using for the front-end? A possible solution would be to use a websocket to transfer the status of your export.